# What is up with npmjs.com? as of 14/09/2019 09:45 CEST

Tags: npmjs

Accessing npmjs gives this from the morning

```
Error 503 All backends failed or unhealthy

All backends failed or unhealthy

Guru Mediation:

Details: cache-bma7035-BMA 1473839041 2911743558

Varnish cache server
```

Is anyone aware what is going on?

#### UPDATE 1:

09.47 CEST: Two minutes later, while writing this question npmjs.com came back online, was down from 8.00 CEST

What was going on? Any clue?

#### UPDATE 2:

As status.npmjs.com came back up again for me, I can see now a message over there. Could not access it before maybe it will help someone

```
Investigating - We're seeing increased 503 rates for both the website and the     
registry for European users. We're suspecting the root cause to be routing-
related and are following up with our CDN provider.
```

Comment: Even if this turns out to be a programming error on their side, it's not on-topic until they post their source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issued was closed

```
New Incident Status: Resolved
Our monitoring reports that error rates returned to base levels and both the     
website and the registry should be accessible to European users as usual.
```